# Fake subfunction in django UnitTest Case (Mocking)

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, testing, mocking

```
def func_b(**kwargs):
    return something


def func_a(request,*args,**kwargs):
    //do something
    b = func_b(**kwargs)
    //do something
    return something
```

I am writing UnitTest for `func_a` but i want to fake the output of `func_b` using mocking or anything similar to mocking in django.
means simply i just want to fake the output of `func_b` and always want to return some static value from `func_b` in Test case.
Is there any way to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `mock.patch` and specify the `return_value`. Here's an example where we are patching the return value of `func_b()` to `Fake value` on the fly:

```
from mock import patch
import unittest


def func_b():
    return "Real value"


def func_a():
    return "The result of func_b is '%s'" % func_b()


class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_fake_value(self):
        with patch('test.func_b', return_value="Fake value") as mock_function:
            self.assertEqual(func_a(), "The result of func_b is 'Fake value'")
```

UPD:

```
with patch.object(module_name, 'func_b') as mock_function:
    mock_function.return_value = "Fake value"
    self.assertEqual(func_a(), "The result of func_b is 'Fake value'")
```

Comment: it is working only if our func_a and func_b are in same file.It doesn't work when func_a and func_b are in different file.
Please guide me.

Comment: i am getting error 'global name mock_function is not defined'.

Comment: module_name is the name of module where 'func_b' is written, right? I am asking it because the UPD part is not working for me.

Comment: @HarshitAgarwal yup. Should work. I've been using this technique for a long time, it's not that I'm guessing. What do you mean by "doesn't work"?

Comment: UPD part only works when func_b is a method of class and our module_name is the class name of that method.